# Passing objects as an argument for a path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Let's say I have a route `get "/:year/:month/:slug", :as => :post"`. To make it work I've already added the following method to the `Post` class:

```
def to_param
  slug
end
```

Now, if I want to use `post_path` route helper I have to pass 3 parameters to it, like: `post_path({ year: '2013', month: '07', slug: 'lorem-ipsum' })`, but since I don't like writing it every time, I've added another method:

```
def uri
  { year: self.published_at.strftime('%Y'), month: self.published_at.strftime('%m'), slug: self.slug }
end
```

It allows me to use `post_path(@post.uri)` to get the path. But it's still not what I want. What I want is to be able to pass an **object** there, like `post_path(@post)`, which gives me the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :year=>#<Post id: nil, slug: "lorem-ipsum", title: nil, body: nil, published: nil, published_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

It can be easily deduced that what Rails really does is something like: `post_path({ year: @post })` which is obviously wrong. However the default routes generated by Rails, which only use `:id` as a parameter, work after passing an object to it. How does Rails do it internally? Does it use any hidden method on `Post` that needs to be overloaded? (I've tried `to_s`, `url_options`, `id`, etc. and none worked.)

### Long story short

**What to do so that Rails sees a hash `{ year: ..., month: ..., slug: ...}` after passing `@post` to `post_path` (and not e.g. `@post.special_method`)?**

#### Edit:

Excerpt from the routes.rb file:

```
scope ':year/:month', :constraints => { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{2}/ } do
  scope ':slug', :constraints => { slug: /[a-z0-9-]+/ } do
    get '/' => 'posts#show', :as => :post
    put '/' => 'posts#update'
    delete '/' => 'posts#destroy'
    get '/edit' => 'posts#edit', :as => :edit_post
  end
end

get 'posts' => 'posts#index', :as => :posts
post 'posts' => 'posts#create'
get 'posts/new' => 'posts#new', :as => :new_post
```

Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code inside uri method to to_param.

```
def to_param
  { year: self.published_at.strftime('%Y'), month: self.published_at.strftime('%m'), slug: self.slug }
end
```

According to Rails APidock, url_for method calls to_param on the passed in object which by default is id.

```
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>
# calls @workshop.to_param which by default returns the id
# => /workshops/5
```

You can refer to [this apidock link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for) for more information

Comment: Still returns the same error, no matter what `to_param` returns. Seems like Rails doesn't use `to_param` at all in my case. Maybe it's because I don't use `resources` in the routes.rb file? I've edited my question to include it as well.